# Error::java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am getting below error

Error::java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object. 
Spark 1.6.1, and scala 2.10.5

Used 
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 --driver-class-path /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/spark/lib/sqljdbc4.jar  to launch the spark-shell

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sqlContext.implicits._

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferScheme","true").option("header","true").load("path_to/data.csv");

df.show()
```

## Below is the full trace

./test.sh

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/xxxx/at732615/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/xxxx/at732615/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/iop/4.2.0.0/spark/lib/spark-assembly-                                                                                       1.6.1_IBM_4-hadoop2.7.2-IBM-12.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10;1.5.0 in central
        found org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.1 in central
        found com.univocity#univocity-parsers;1.5.1 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 331ms :: artifacts dl 5ms
        :: modules in use:
        com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10;1.5.0 from central in [default]
        com.univocity#univocity-parsers;1.5.1 from central in [default]
        org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.1 from central in [default]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   3   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
        confs: [default]
        0 artifacts copied, 3 already retrieved (0kB/8ms)
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_77)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead is set but does not apply in client mode.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.
Loading csv.scala...
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sqlContext.implicits._
conf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@4ccfd904
sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@32a53a59
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@219acda9
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getInputFormat(HadoopRDD.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1307)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1302)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1342)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1341)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine$lzycompute(CsvRelation.scala:269)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine(CsvRelation.scala:265)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.inferSchema(CsvRelation.scala:242)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.<init>(CsvRelation.scala:74)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:171)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:46)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:50)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:52)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:54)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:56)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:58)
        at <init>(<console>:60)
        at .<init>(<console>:64)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:680)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at scala.reflect.io.Streamable$Chars$class.applyReader(Streamable.scala:104)
        at scala.reflect.io.File.applyReader(File.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$savingReplayStack(SparkILoop.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.savingReader(SparkILoop.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom(SparkILoop.scala:675)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadCommand$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:740)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadCommand$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withFile(SparkILoop.scala:733)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadCommand(SparkILoop.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(SparkILoop.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(SparkILoop.scala:344)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands$LineCmd.apply(LoopCommands.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:809)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadFiles$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:910)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadFiles$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:908)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:908)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:995)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 110 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec not found.
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.<init>(CompressionCodecFactory.java:180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.configure(TextInputFormat.java:45)
        ... 115 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:132)
        ... 117 more

<console>:32: error: not found: value df
              df.show()
```

Comment: I can also see below message in full trace

"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec not found."  Not sure if that is related to my issue

Comment: You have a ClassNotFoundException.  Make sure the LzopCodec class file is on your class path.

Comment: ok, Below is the jar file file which I think is the one that I need

hadoop-lzo-0.4.15.jar

please confirm